# how to drop a series of pandas columns by multiple keyword

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have received a pandas dataframe.
It is full of unnecessary features that I would like to remove.
Right now I am doing the following, which is dirty
How could I get this in a more pythonic way?

```
 features_to_include= mydf.columns.tolist()
 features_to_include=[f for f in features_to_include if 'stopword1' not in f]

 features_to_include=[f for f in features_to_include if 'stopwordN' not in f]
```

[... other 90 of those]

```
    features_to_include=[f for f in features_to_include if 'password1' in f]
    features_to_include=[f for f in features_to_include if 'passwordN' in f]
```

[... other 90 of those]

EDIT:'stopword1' and 'password1' are **not** in `X.columns`
an example name of a `X.columns` could be: `feature99_stopword1`

Comment: Do you not have a list of columns you want to drop?

Comment: not quite... I have a variable list of columns, from which I have to remove/keep stuff based on a set of keywords e.g. using filter(like=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
L = ['stopword1','stopwordN','password1', 'passwordN']
#thanks roganjosh for suggestion
L = set(['stopword1','stopwordN','password1', 'passwordN'])

mydf = mydf.loc[:, mydf.columns.str.contains('|'.join(L))]
```

**Sample**:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'feature99_stopword1':list('abcdef'),
                   'feature99_stopword':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'd_stopword1':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'password1':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})
print (mydf)
  feature99_stopword1  feature99_stopword  C  d_stopword1  password1  F
0                   a                   4  7            1          5  a
1                   b                   5  8            3          3  a
2                   c                   4  9            5          6  a
3                   d                   5  4            7          9  b
4                   e                   5  2            1          2  b
5                   f                   4  3            0          4  b

L = ['stopword1','stopwordN','password1', 'passwordN']
mydf = mydf.loc[:, mydf.columns.str.contains('|'.join(L))]
print (mydf)
  feature99_stopword1  d_stopword1  password1
0                   a            1          5
1                   b            3          3
2                   c            5          6
3                   d            7          9
4                   e            1          2
5                   f            0          4
```

Comment: Wouldn't converting `L` to a `set` be better? Or does `isin` do that naturally?

Comment: mydf = mydf.loc[:, mydf.columns.contains('|'.join(L))] fails because a boolean is returned

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.filter(regex='password|stopword1', axis=1)
```

Or if we have a list:

```
cols = ['password','passwordN','stopword1','stopwordN']
mydf.filter(regex='|'.join(cols), axis=1)
```